# basic formatting a strings in python

Tags: python, string, format

Any idea why the count1 variable doesn't format to align to the right?

```py
count1 = 5
games = 7

print(format("correct guesses: %s" %(count1), '>5s'))
print(format("this is how many games played: %s" %(games), '>5s'))
```

output should be so both numbers align together on the right side
so something like this:

```py
correct guesses:                   5
this is how many games played:     7
```

Comment: What output do you want. `correct guesses: 2>5s`

Comment: edited to show wanted output, thanks @SharimIqbal

Comment: Because you're trying to `format` the entire string "correct guesses: 5". You just want to `format` the value `5`, and *then* interpolate it into the  string "correct guesses: %s".

Comment: So I need to format the value first? You can't format the value within a nested print?

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply formatting to the string as if there were 2 columns of data:

```py
count1 = 5
games = 7

print("correct guesses:".ljust(30), format("%s" % count1, '>5s'))
print("this is how many games played:".ljust(30), format("%s" % games, '>5s'))
```

Or using f-strings:

```py
print(f"{'correct guesses:':<30} {count1:>5}")
print(f"{'this is how many games played:':<30} {games:>5}")
```

Output:

```
correct guesses:                   5
this is how many games played:     7
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I got it to work with the following:

```py
count1 = 5
games = 7

print(("correct guesses: "), format("%g" %count1, '>19s'))
print(("This is how many games played: "), format("%g" %games, '>5s'))
```

```py
output was:
correct guesses:                    5
This is how many games played:      7
```

19 was used to ensure the two lined up due to the extra characters in the string.